# Como fijar ventana de resultados del componente mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material

Usando material versión 7 existe alguna manera de fijar la ventana de resultados en una sola posición y evitar que la ventana se muestre en diferentes posiciones?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si selecciono el valor steak la ventana de resultados se muestra en una posición, pero si selecciono tacos, ahora la ventana se muestra de resultados se muestra en otra posición, básicamente sobre el texto, ¿es posible evitar ese comportamiento?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes conseguirlo a través del input `disableOptionCentering` del `mat-select`

```
<mat-select [disableOptionCentering]="true">
    ...
</mat-select>
```

En el siguiente enlace tienes toda la API del mat-select de la v7 de angular material. https://v7.material.angular.io/components/select/api

un saludo